# Most elegant way to get a array with all combinations of given elements

Tags: julia, combinations

What is currently the most elegant way to get a array with column names containing all combinations of given elements? Some closest analogue of the function `expand.grid()` from R. All the discussions I've met on this issue have been about either a slightly different formulation of the problem, or were conducted in the days of very old versions of Julia. The most rational solution that I found at the moment looks like this:

```
using DataFrames
xy = [[x,y] for x in 0:0.25:1 for y in 0:0.25:1]
xy_array = permutedims(reshape(hcat(xy...), (length(xy[1]), length(xy))))
df = DataFrame(x = xy_array[:,1], y = xy_array[:,2])
```

A similar expression in R can be written much more compactly:

```
xy_comb <- expand.grid(x=seq(0, 1, 0.25), y=seq(0, 1, 0.25))
```

Is there any more concise form to writing a same expression in Julia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me show several options that will also show the integration of DataFrames.jl with Tables.jl and how it can be used in this case.

You can do e.g. this:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x=Float64[], y=Float64[])
0×2 DataFrame

julia> foreach(x -> push!(df, x), Iterators.product(0:0.25:1, 0:0.25:1))

julia> df
25×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x        y
     │ Float64  Float64
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │    0.0      0.0
   2 │    0.25     0.0
   3 │    0.5      0.0
  ⋮  │    ⋮        ⋮
  23 │    0.5      1.0
  24 │    0.75     1.0
  25 │    1.0      1.0
         19 rows omitted
```

or this (this will be faster, but the former pattern is useful in general situations when you generate rows of a data frame dynamically):

```
julia> rename!(DataFrame(Iterators.product(0:0.25:1, 0:0.25:1)), [:x, :y])
25×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x        y
     │ Float64  Float64
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │    0.0      0.0
   2 │    0.25     0.0
   3 │    0.5      0.0
  ⋮  │    ⋮        ⋮
  23 │    0.5      1.0
  24 │    0.75     1.0
  25 │    1.0      1.0
         19 rows omitted
```

The problem with `DataFrame(Iterators.product(0:0.25:1, 0:0.25:1))` is that the default column names are `"1"` and `"2"` which you probably want to change.

Therefore you could also generate `NamedTuples` instead of `Tuples` like this:

```
julia> DataFrame((x=x,y=y) for x in 0:0.25:1 for y in 0:0.25:1)
25×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x        y
     │ Float64  Float64
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │    0.0      0.0
   2 │    0.0      0.25
   3 │    0.0      0.5
  ⋮  │    ⋮        ⋮
  23 │    1.0      0.5
  24 │    1.0      0.75
  25 │    1.0      1.0
         19 rows omitted
```

with a different order of rows.